# pyspark reading parquet files partitioned data using Dynamic Date Ranges

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

My Dataset is the following:

```
year=yyyy
 |---month=mm
 |   |---day=dd
 |   |   |---<parquet-files>
```

I have got it working in a static way for today and tomorrow data using:

```
   (year = year(current_date()) and month = month(current_date()) and day = 
   dayofmonth(current_date())) or 
   (year = year(date_sub(current_date(), 1)) and month = month(date_sub(current_date(), 1)) and 
   day = dayofmonth(date_sub(current_date(), 1)))
```

However I need to pull a date range from Today to X days back. I have tried (Datediff in a filter but that just doesnt work with parquet files).

```
   DateDiff(current_date(),to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-', day))) <= %s
   and
   DateDiff(current_date(),to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-', day))) >= 0
```

I was wondering if it is possible and what a possible solution would be?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following will do

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

X = 5
today = date.today()
dates = [today-timedelta(days=x) for x in range(X)]

table_path = "hdfs:///path/to/parquet/table/year={year}/month={month}/day={day}/*"

paths = [table_path.format(year=date.year, month=date.month, day=date.day) for date in dates]

df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths)
```